# undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, variables, view, instance-variables

I want to dynamically create checkboxes with the users in the database, which shall be possible to choose (one or many). However, I am apparently doing something wrong because the code below gives me the following error:

```
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
...
<% @users.each do |user| %> <--- the line with the error
```

**the controller:**

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
    ...

    def new
      @project = Project.new
      @users = (current_user.blank? ? User.all : User.find(:all, :conditions => ["id != ?", current_user.id]))
    end

    ...
end
```

**the view (new.html.erb):**

```
<%= form_for @project do |f| %>
    <div class="alert alert-block">  
        <%= f.error_messages %>
    </div>
    <div class="text_field">
        <%= f.label :title%>
        <%= f.text_field :title%>
    </div>
    <div class="text_field">
        <%= f.label :description%>
        <%= f.text_field :description%>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <%= f.label :start_date%>
        <%= f.date_select :start_date %>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <%= f.label :end_date%>
        <%= f.date_select :end_date %>
    </div>
    <% @users.each do |user| %>
        <%= check_box_tag "project[member_ids][]", user.id, @project.member_ids.include?(user.id), :id => "user_#{user.id}" %> 
        <%= label_tag "user_#{user.id}", user.first_name %>
    <% end %>
    <div class="checkbox">
</div>
    <div class="submit">
        <%= f.submit "Spara" %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

**the model:**

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :tickets, :dependent => :destroy

  ... validations ...

  attr_accessible :user_id, :title, :description, :start_date, :end_date
end
```

I have five users in my database, so the table isn't empty or anything. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I would suggest to include `@users= ...` statement in the `create` action of your controller also .

Answer (score 7):

The error happens when you try to submit the form and fails validation.  If your create action renders the `new` template, that's where your problem lies.

as suggested by one of the commenters, you can declare `@users` in your create action.  But I suggest only declare it when it fails validation (to reduce the number of db queries by 1 and to reduce the creation of unnecessary active record objects) like in the following code

```
def create
  @project = Project.new params[:project]

  if @project.save
    redirect_to @project
  else
    @users = User.all # only declare this here when it is actually needed
    render :new
  end
end
```

Comment: Had similar issure with rails 4.2 and this answer helped me fix it.